# Making GTK# File Chooser to Select File Only

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk#

Im using GTK# `FileChooserDialog`  widget.The problem is that even though the widget is named file chooser you can select folders with it and it returns folder names also.
Is there any way by which i can restrict it to choosing only files? I have checked almost class all properties i could not find any.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can restrict the action by defining its Action-Property in the constructor

```
private void OpenOFD()
{
    Gtk.FileChooserDialog filechooser =
        new Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Choose the file to open",
            this,
            FileChooserAction.Open,
            "Cancel",ResponseType.Cancel,
            "Open",ResponseType.Accept);

    if (filechooser.Run() == (int)ResponseType.Accept) 
    {
        System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filechooser.Filename);
        file.Close();
    }

    filechooser.Destroy();
}
```

There are 4 FolderChooserActions:

1. CreateFolder: Indicates a mode for creating a new folder. The chooser will let the user name an existing or new folder
2. Open: Will only pick an existing file
3. Save: Will pick an existing file or type in a new filename
4. SelectFolder: Pick an existring folder

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, that behavior depends on the [Action](http://buttle.shangorilla.com/1.1/handlers/monodoc.ashx?link=P%3aGtk.FileChooserWidget.Action) property:

- If it is set to `FileChooserAction.Open` or `FileChooserAction.Save`, only files can selected.
- If it is set to `FileChooserAction.SelectFolder` or `FileChooserAction.CreateFolder`, only folders can be selected.